# Why are my web fonts files not being loaded?

Tags: css, webfonts

I am wondering, why **only two of my six web font files** are being loaded.

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Constructa';
  src: url(/content/themes/blog-theme/fonts/Constructa-Regular.woff);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'TranSerif HdlUltrabold';
  src: url(/content/themes/blog-theme/fonts/TranSerif-HdlUltrabold.woff);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AvantGarde Bold';
  src: url(/content/themes/blog-theme/fonts/AvantGarBol.woff);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ChronicleTextG3';
  src: url(/content/themes/blog-theme/fonts/ChronicleTextG3.woff);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Antenna Bold';
  src: url(/content/themes/blog-theme/fonts/Antenna-Bold.otf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Antenna Thin';
  src: url(/content/themes/blog-theme/fonts/Antenna-Thin.otf);
}
```

The "Network" tab in Google Chrome does not show any 404s. Neither does it show my font files being loaded.

[image: Network traffic in chrome]

I experience the same issue in other browsers, so I would suggest, that it is my code that is causing troubles.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
Benedikt

P.S.: Of course, I did check the availability of the other web fonts. They are existing on the given paths. Just not loaded.

Comment: Are you using all of the fonts in your css (or just loading them)?

Comment: I've heard in some browsers if the file names don't match the embedded font names it can glitch out.

Comment: Some fonts were not used on the tested page. Therefore, chrome did not load it. @nils was right!

Answer (score 9):

Just to give an answer as to why this is happening. In the [*CSS Fonts Module*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts) Specification (Section [*4.8 Font loading guidelines*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-loading)) it says:

> The @font-face rule is designed to allow lazy loading of font resources that are only downloaded when used within a document.

So since you specified all the fonts via `@font-face` but only used two of them in your subsequent CSS, browsers such as Chrome and Firefox wont download them (which saves a lot of bandwidth, especially on mobile devices).